# Wiremock does not respond

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wiremock

I have an integration test for rest api microservers that stubs some of the external resources. Most of them work, but there is a particular one which becomes not available during the test.

- Other tests stubbed the same way work
- Given stubbing works when request is sent directly from the test or if called from postman while test is in Thread.sleep()
- Stubbing does not work when the same request as used above is sent from one of the microservices called by the test or from postman if a microservice is paused (paused on a debug breakpoint). Other stubs work in these conditions.

> ```
> @ClassRule
> public static WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(
>         wireMockConfig()
>             .port(8080)
>             .usingFilesUnderDirectory("src/integration-test/resources"));
> ```

```
       public static void stubExtService(WireMockRule wireMockRule) {
                wireMockRule.stubFor(post(urlPathEqualTo("/my/url"))
                    .willReturn(aResponse().withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withBodyFile("json/response.json")));
        }
```

Comment: yeah, a typo. fixed it in the question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have not located it in the code yet, my entry point service was responding and then processing the request asynchronously. Meanwhile, the test was receiving the response and shutting down along with WireMock, and microservices could not access the mocked resource any longer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the issue is that the test is finishing and WireMock shutting down before the async operation has completed. In this situation you can use [Awaitility](http://www.awaitility.org/) to wait (polling) for an expected request.

Here's an example in WireMock's tests:
https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/PostServeActionExtensionTest.java#L85